# Why do I lose my UTF-8 BOM when changing file attributes?

Tags: delphi, utf-8, byte-order-mark, file-attributes

I've a test Delphi application that uses TFileStream to write a UTF-8 BOM to a text file, followed by one dummy line of text.

All works as expected, and using the hex viewer plugin for Notepad++ I see the BOM in the output text file.  However, if I then change the attribute of the text file (either programmatically in Delphi or via Windows explorer) on re-opening the file the BOM has been removed.

Sample code that writes the BOM and dummy data to the file:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  cFilename = 'myfile.txt';
var
  fs : TFileStream;
  gBOM : TBytes;
  gStr : RawByteString;
begin
  fs := TFileStream.Create(cFilename, fmCreate, fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    gBOM := TEncoding.UTF8.GetPreamble;
    fs.WriteBuffer(PAnsiChar(gBOM)^, Length(gBOM));

    // Dummy data
    gStr := UTF8Encode('Dummy string') + AnsiChar(#13) + AnsiChar(#10);
    fs.WriteBuffer(PAnsiChar(gStr)^, Length(gStr));

    // If you read the file now the BOM will be present, however
    // the follow line appears to remove it.
    FileSetAttr(cFilename, faReadOnly);

  finally
    FreeAndNil(fs);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: So, you're saying that before you call `FileSetAttr`, Windows Explorer showed the file's size to be 17 bytes, but after that call, it showed the file to be 14 bytes? Do you observe any difference in behavior if you change the file's attributes *after* you close the file instead of before?

Comment: The behaviour you describe does not occur.

Comment: Since you have a file handle already open, you should probably be using the Windows API function `SetFileInformationByHandle` to set the attributes. But I don't think that really matters.

Comment: I believe, when you claim `If you read the file` you really open it in some editor, then when closing editor you do SAVE the file - and that is what removes the BOM, not the Delphi program. I heard reports about people, opening binary files in MS Word, then closing Word and claiming file was broken (and it realyl was after Word saved it on closing). I believe your text editor did that to file and removed BOM. Use SysInternals Process Monitor and do actual tracking of all the programs that ever did written to that filename.

Comment: Also  what is the file name ? Windows UAC Virtualization could not substitute the file ?

Comment: Try to call `FileSetAttr` *after* `try/finally` block (to make sure that `TFileStream` handle is closed and flashed to disk). but as @DavidHeffernan commented, I'm not sure that it will actually make a difference.

Comment: if you get this same result by changing the attributes in windows explorer then as everyone else has alluded to some other application on your machine is rewritting the file automagically.

Answer (score 4):

Setting file attributes has no effect on a file's existing content.  The only way the BOM can disappear is if the file's content is copied to a new file with the BOM omitted.  Setting attributes does not do that.

Keep in mind that you are working with a relative file path, so it is possible that maybe you have multiple copies of the file on your machine and are looking at the wrong file.  Always use full paths instead.

A simpler way to write a BOM and text into a file with `TEncoding` is to use the `TStreamWriter` class instead.

You should call `FileSetAttr()` after closing the file to ensure it actually takes effect, and you need to call `FileGetAttr()` before calling `FileSetAttr()` to ensure existing attributes are preserved correctly.

Try this instead:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
const 
  cFilename = 'c:\path to\myfile.txt'; 
var 
  sw : TStreamWriter;
  Attrs: Integer; 
begin 
  sw := TStreamWriter.Create(cFilename, False, TEncoding.UTF8); 
  try 
    sw.WriteLine('Dummy string');
  finally 
    sw.Free; 
  end; 
  Attrs := FileGetAttr(cFilename);
  if Attrs <> -1 then 
    FileSetAttr(cFilename, Attrs or faReadOnly); 
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
// GetFileInformationByHandle() is declared in Windows.pas, but SetFileInformationByHandle() is not!

type
  _FILE_INFO_BY_HANDLE_CLASS = ( 
    FileBasicInfo,
    FileStandardInfo,
    FileNameInfo,
    FileRenameInfo,
    FileDispositionInfo,
    FileAllocationInfo,
    FileEndOfFileInfo,
    FileStreamInfo,
    FileCompressionInfo,
    FileAttributeTagInfo,
    FileIdBothDirectoryInfo
);
FILE_INFO_BY_HANDLE_CLASS = _FILE_INFO_BY_HANDLE_CLASS;

_FILE_BASIC_INFO = record
  CreationTime: LARGE_INTEGER;
  LastAccessTime: LARGE_INTEGER;
  LastWriteTime: LARGE_INTEGER;
  ChangeTime: LARGE_INTEGER;
  FileAttributes: DWORD;
end;
FILE_BASIC_INFO = _FILE_BASIC_INFO;

function SetFileInformationByHandle(hFile: THandle; FileInformationClass: FILE_INFO_BY_HANDLE_CLASS; lpFileInformation: Pointer; dwBufferSize: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall; external 'kernel32' delayed;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
const 
  cFilename = 'c:\path to\myfile.txt'; 
var 
  sw : TStreamWriter;
  fi: TByHandleFileInformation;
  bi: FILE_BASIC_INFO;
  Attrs: Integer;
  AttrsSet: Boolean;
begin 
  AttrsSet := False;

  sw := TStreamWriter.Create(cFilename, False, TEncoding.UTF8); 
  try 
    sw.WriteLine('Dummy string');

    if CheckWin32Version(6, 0) then
    begin
      if GetFileInformationByHandle(TFileStream(sw.BaseStream).Handle, fi) then
      begin
        bi.CreationTime.LowPart := fi.ftCreationTime.dwLowDateTime;
        bi.CreationTime.HighPart := fi.ftCreationTime.dwHighDateTime;

        bi.LastAccessTime.LowPart := fi.ftLastAccessTime.dwLowDateTime;
        bi.LastAccessTime.HighPart := fi.ftLastAccessTime.dwHighDateTime;

        bi.LastWriteTime.LowPart := fi.ftLastWriteTime.dwLowDateTime;
        bi.LastWriteTime.HighPart := fi.ftLastWriteTime.dwHighDateTime;

        bi.ChangeTime := bi.LastWriteTime;

        bi.FileAttributes := fi.dwFileAttributes or FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY;
        AttrsSet := SetFileInformationByHandle(TFileStream(sw.BaseStream).Handle, FileBasicInfo, @bi, SizeOf(bi));
      end;
  finally 
    sw.Free; 
  end; 

  if not AttrsSet then
  begin
    Attrs := FileGetAttr(cFilename);
    if Attrs <> -1 then 
      FileSetAttr(cFilename, Attrs or faReadOnly); 
  end;
end;
```